# Codeigniter SMTP error sending email: relay access denied on 554 5.7.1

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send email using SMTP codeigniter, but i have this error: SMTP Server response: 554 5.7.1 xxxx@gmail.com: relay access denied.

this only happen when the recipient is on the gmail account.
i was originally using zimbra account to send email through the system.
it worked all fine when sending the email to the same zimbra account, but error when i want to send it to gmail account.

here is my email configuration code:

```
$config = [
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'utf-8',
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'starttls'  => 'true',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://zimbra.xmission.com',
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxx',  // Email 
        'smtp_pass'   => 'xxxx',  // Password 
        'smtp_port'   => 587,
        'crlf'    => "\r\n",
        'newline' => "\r\n"
    ];

    // Load library email dan konfigurasinya
    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    // Email dan nama pengirim
    $this->email->from('Antifraud@bankneo.co.id', 'Anti Fraud');

    // Email penerima
    $this->email->to($recipient); // Ganti dengan email tujuan

    // Subject email
    $this->email->subject('[no-reply] OTP ACCESS ON WHISTLEBLOWING SYSTEM - '.date('Y-m-d'));

    // Isi email
    $this->email->message("Hello ".$recipient." This is your One Time Password (OTP). \n".$otp."\n Your OTP will be available for the next 1 Minute.");
```

Comment: This is not a programming problem. The mail server is telling you it won't relay mail to the address you've asked it to. You need to find a server that will allow you to do this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question, but a matter of finding a server that allows relay.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i will now close the question